# cumulative update package 5 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 encountered error

Tags: 2013, distributedcache, app-fabric

When patching App Fabric 1.1 CU5 I encountered " the Feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable."
[image]

I used the instructions provided in KB document to capture the temp file and point that into packages folder, but the executable never created packages folder and the msi file as described  in the window.

How do I fix this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: right click on file  > properties and make sure it is not blocked.

Comment: It is not blocked and exe file randomly creates unique folder everytime we run it, then it doesn't have any .msi file created

Comment: when i download the CU5 it si 32 MB named like this WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64. try to download directly from the site.

Comment: I am doing Distributed Cache/ App fabric CU 5 for sharepoint 2013 , I don't find file that is 32 MB, can you send me the link of the site you are referencing to?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2932678

Comment: I am using the same link it where I chosed 64 bit  ENU package which is 1.6 mb. Which is named as AppFabric1.1-KB2932678-x64-ENU.exe

Comment: try this one http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115

Comment: I already have appfabric 1.1 installed, the link looks like download file for older version released at 2012?

Comment: I am not sure why you getting the above error, i just download the enu package and it works fine....are you trying to install it from network location or local drive? move the file to root directory of OS drive and then try....that trick works sometime

Comment: This is How I fixed the issue :It seems to me like the windows installer entry for that software was either missing or incorrect. I located the section in the registry that pointed to the source file and I just edited it to match the other server. Then I ran the install again and it went through without an issue

Comment: Now other question  is where does DistributedCacheService.exe.config file live

Comment: C:\windows\system32\appfabric\DistributedCacheService.exe.config

Comment: thanks all set. something I came across after I installed the patch. I was receiving " Use-CacheCluster : ErrorCode<ERRPS002>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Invalid provider and connection string read. Please provide the values manually." While attempting to get to the cluster via powershell. I fixed this error my adding connection string and provider information in the registry which is located at "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Configuration"

Comment: @allegrooctopus Could you add that last comment as an answer, and (after two days) mark it as the accepted answer. It help others having the same problem you did. Thank you!